# JS Регексп для получения эпизодов в youtube видео

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Недавно на ютубе появились эпизоды, а может и не недавно. В своем проекте мне нужно выдавать некоторую информацию об ютуб видео, эпизоды не исключение. Для уточнения покажу, что за эпизоды.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjGjl.png

Нужно получить временную метку начала и описание к этой метке.
Я знаю то, что эти метки описываются в описании под видео в строгом формате, поэтому проблем не должно быть.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVEDI.png

Из своих усилий я смог получить лишь само время, т.е метки, но не описание к ним, и наоборот, только уже целиком.

`^([^\n]+)\\n` - цепляет `[00:00] - Episode title`

UPD: `0:00 - Episode title` тоже работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: Не совсем правильное применение в данном случае...

```
regex = /^\[?([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})\]?[^A-z]+(.*)$/gm;
str = '[00:00] - Episode title';
result = str.replace(regex, 'Это время: $1, это название: $2');
console.log(result);
```

Лучше использовать `match`, для создания массива:

```js
regex = /^\[?([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})\]?[^A-z]+(.*)$/m;
str = '[00:00] - Episode title';
result = str.match(regex);
console.log('Название эпизода: '+result[2]+', время эпизода: ' +result[1]);
```

Сам шаблон регулярного выражения:
`^\[?([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})\]?[^A-z]+(.*)`
`^` - начало строки
`\[?` символ скобочки(необязательный элемент, квантификатор `?` аналогичен `{0,1}` и означает отсутствие или только одного совпадения
`[0-9]{1,2}` - одна или две цифры
`:` - явное появление одного символа `:`
`[^A-z]+` - все кроме символов латинского алфавита, квантификатор `+` означает появление одного и более совпадений
`.*` - ноль и более любых символов.
`$` - символ конца строки
Части с временем и названием взяты в круглые скобки, таким образом мы создаем группу захвата, которую в дальнейшем можно вызывать, нумерация проходит слева направо.
Первая группа будет время, вторая название.